# Destroy session using popup message

Tags: javascript, php

I want that when I click the logout button then it will destroy the session it runs perfectly but the issue is when I click on the cancel button of the popup it destroys the session even then.

below is the code.

index.php

```
<script>

  function logout(){
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')){
        return true;
        <?php echo session_unset(); ?>
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>

<a href="<?php echo PATH_HREF;?>index.php?p=registration" target="_blank" onclick="return logout();" class="blue"><b>click the Register link</b></a>
```

Comment: because your code `<?php echo session_unset();?>` always execute. You need to redirect your current page to logout page if user confirm logout

Comment: You cannot run PHP code directly from javascript. PHP runs on the server, javascript runs on the browser!

Comment: Also you should close the `<script>` tag with a `</script>` tag before continuing to output HTML

Comment: but i have to redirect to registration page whenever i click on logout.

Comment: More easiest explanation: Client send request to server. On your server executes php code and send response to client. Then on clients side executes JS code. So php code run first, then JS. That is why user has already log out when response came from server

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy session without AJAX or relaoding. In your case , the following ligne

```
<?php echo session_unset();  ?>
```

Is executed when the page are displayed, Javascript doesn't execute php instruction.

So create a WebForm who will send a parameter in post or do ajax =)

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo session_unset(); ?>` have already destroyed the session whether confirm or not user to logout. because `<?php echo session_unset(); ?>` have already executed and destroied the session

Try this solution instead

create a new file logout.php with the code

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy(); // or  session_unset('session_name'); to dystroy individual session
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/home.php"); // to redirect user after logout
?>
```

and on javascript side

```
<script>

  function logout(){
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')){
        window.location = "/logout.php";
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have a logout file but if i go to the logout file then it will not redirect to the registration file. i want that when i click on logout then it will redirect me to registration page.

Comment: do `header("Location: registration.php");` in logout file which will do the redirection and don't Print anything before `header()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unset session on registration page.

Comment: Please describe a more details.